# How to access object variable inside self-executing anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, object, variables

Please look at this code:

```
var someObject = 
{
    x: 3,
    y: (function()
    {
        var z = // HOW TO ACCESS x HERE?

        return {
            // whatever
        };
    })()
};
```

Is there any possibility to access "x" variable inside function, without creating any variables outside "someObject" object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The object hasn't been created so `x` doesn't exist at the time that statement is evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

Not a fine way but this is the only way you can access x variable in this case

```js
var someObject = 
{
    x: 3,
    y: (function()
    {  
      setTimeout(function(){
        var z = someObject.x
        console.log(z);
        },1);
        
    })()
};
```